# Updating the database with advanced custom fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, save-post

I'm having a real problem with updating a database table using advanced custom fields within a custom post type.

I have a table in the database called 'wp_company_profiles' with fields 'address_1' and 'address_2', and have two advanced custom fields set up with the same values. I am trying to put together a hook that will update the table fields when a particular post in updated.

Below is the code I am using, but I can't figure out why it won't work.

```
function update_company_profile($post_ID)  {
    global $wpdb;

    if ($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )) $post_ID = $parent_id;

    $address_1 = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'address_1', true);
    $address_2 = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'address_2', true);

    $sql = $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_company_profiles SET
            address_1 = '{$address_1}',
            address_2 = '{$address_2}',
            WHERE pid = {$post_ID}");

    $wpdb->query($sql);
}

add_action('save_post', 'update_company_profile');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the query twice and passing the result of the first query to the second query.  Give this a try.  You might also consider using the update function from wpdb instead of running an arbitrary query because it doesn't look like you're doing any data sanitization or nonce checks.  If you do want to query, you should use prepare.

```
function update_company_profile($post_ID)  {
    global $wpdb;

    if ($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )) $post_ID = $parent_id;

    $address_1 = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'address_1', true);
    $address_2 = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'address_2', true);

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_company_profiles SET
            address_1 = '%s',
            address_2 = '%s',
            WHERE pid = %d", $address_1, $address_2, $post_ID);

    $wpdb->query($sql);
}

add_action('save_post', 'update_company_profile');
```

Comment: Sure thing.  Do you mind hitting the check mark to mark this as the accepted answer?  Happy coding!